# How to compile this C++ code on Linux with relevant header files?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to compile [this C++ code](https://github.com/petrmanek/enigma/) in my `Linux` box using `g++` but it fails with the following error:

```
enigma/Enigma# g++ -I . main.cpp -o main
In file included from machine.h:14:0,
                 from tests.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:10:
plug.h:13:2: warning: #import is a deprecated GCC extension [-Wdeprecated]
 #import "util.h"
  ^~~~~~
/tmp/ccxyoEC2.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `test_machine_encode_decode()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

<del>The error indicates that the compiler cannot find the tests.h file present in the same folder.</del>  How can I compile and run this code?

I now understand that I needed to link the object files together, I did so using:

```
g++ -c *.cpp
g++ *.o -o enig
```

It still does not work though, the resulting binary executes with `./enig` but is broken and does not function as intended:

```
Entire encoded message: TZQA
Decoding now...
Entire decoded message: AHOJ

Entire encoded message: HBIU
Decoding now...
Entire decoded message: AHOJ

Entire encoded message: ZSNE
Decoding now...
Entire decoded message: AHOJ

Entire encoded message: ICRH
```

It just keeps encoding and decoding those random texts as opposed to the functionality mentioned on the git page I shared above.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: "_The error indicates that the compiler cannot find the tests.h_" No it doesn't. The **warning** indicates that `#import` is a deprecated extension. The **error** indicates that the **linker** can't find the **definition** of the function. And judging from command line you are using to compile your program - you aren't linking with the file containing the definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You've edited your question to ask something completely different, making the current answers useless. Please revert it and ask a separate question if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

> The error indicates that the compiler cannot find the tests.h file present in the same folder.

No, it doesn't. In fact, the compiler successfully compiled `main.cpp`.

The error indicates that the linker cannot find `test_machine_encode_decode`. This is hardly surprising, since `test_machine_encode_decode` is defined in `test.cpp`. You have to link the object files of `main.cpp` and `test.cpp` to get a complete executable.

Comment: "You have to link main.cpp with test.cpp to get a complete executable." -- How do I do that?

Comment: @learnerX Look at the duplicate you were pointed to to see how.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the actual code, you'll see that main only calls the `test_machine_encode_decode()` Unit-test. You'll have to implement the functionality from the readme yourself or you search through the git history and try to find out, if the program actually worked in the past.